# Magento 2.3 - How to Get product-salable-quantity using REST API?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, magento2.3.0

I followed the Magento documentation regarding fetching Product Salable quantity using REST API.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/modules/inventory/check-salable-quantity.html

But I'm getting only **0 value** for all products when I use **get-product-salable-quantity API.**

**Can anyone help with this ASAP?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check product salable quantity you can use this endpoint:

```
/V1/stockItems/{productSku}
```

or

```
/V1/stockStatuses/{productSku}
```

method **GET**

more magento 2 endpoints here https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

especially **catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1** group

Comment: Thanks I can able to get stock statuses of products. Can you help me in getting the same **salable quantity  and max_sale_qty** values for the product **programmatically** ?

Comment: If You want to use api, just call that endpoints i meant ealier.

Comment: and take what You need from product object. 
salable quantity is under **data['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty']**
Tell me if this solve your problems. Unfortunatelly I don't know what You mean about **max_sale_qty**

Comment: protected $_productloader;  


  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader

    ) {


        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

Comment: Thanks I got all the required stock datas using the above API, but except one.
Can you also help me in getting "Source Item Status", explained below.

With the above API we can only get the stock statuses of current store or source.
In Magento 2.3 we use MSI,  I have two sources(source1 and source2). I need to fetch the "Source Item Status" of both the Sources programmatically or using API. Can you please help me with that ?

Comment: Did You check this site? 
https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi/wiki/Order-Processing-with-REST-API-on-MSI
or this one:
https://webkul.com/blog/introduction-to-magento2-multi-source-inventory/